# TYPO3 seo make canonical tag slide trough rootline

Tags: overriding, seo, typoscript, typo3-9.x, canonical-link

Using older versions of EXT:yoast I was used that once the **canonical tag** was defined, it was **used troughout the website** from that point on (if no specific new canonical was introduced) ...

Now that this feature is dealt with by the core extension SEO, this is missing and I need to fill out every single page if the whole site needs to be indicated as duplicate for another site.

If a 'content slide trough rootline' disturbes something there could be a boolean variable introduced that sets this behaviour only if desired ...

Anybody knows how to override the core behaviour and **add this for TYPO3 v9 and up ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a question: if the whole site is a duplicate of another website, wouldn't it be more logical to just set the website to "noindex,nofollow" within the robots metatag?

If you want to override the default canonical I think the easiest way would be to XCLASS the `CanonicalGenerator` and the method `checkDefaultCanonical`.

Basic example (which should work with 9, 10 and 11), within your site extension's `ext_localconf.php`:

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][\TYPO3\CMS\Seo\Canonical\CanonicalGenerator::class] = [
    'className' => \Vendor\Ext\Xclass\CanonicalGenerator::class
];
```

And then (basic example of) the class:

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Ext\Xclass;

class CanonicalGenerator extends \TYPO3\CMS\Seo\Canonical\CanonicalGenerator
{
    protected function checkDefaultCanonical(): string
    {
        $canonical = parent::checkDefaultCanonical();
        return str_replace('yourdomain.ext', 'desireddomain.ext', $canonical);
    }
}
```

This is of course a basic example without any configuration possibilities, but this would still leave you the possibility to manually set a canonical on a page, this method is only executed when there's no other canonical available.

Comment: yes, of course quite a wrestle to add some configuration but i got it working, with noindex nofollow i'm kind of in the same boat, also that does not slide trough the rootline, should I not apply that setting to any page in the site ?